What could be the purpose of multiple mount positions for the rear fins of a (turbine-powered) missile?
The official photos of the Iranian 358 missile have an interesting detail. Apparently the rear fins can be mounted at different positions on the body, given the multiple mounts.

I have circled the extra mounts visible. What (flexibility?) could be gained by doing so, i.e. varying the mount position of the rear fins?
(The 358 is powered by a gas turbine, making it a "loitering SAM" against drones, according to Wikipedia, although I don't know if that has any relationship with my Q.)

Other images of the 358 show multiple fins attached. Not just the normal 2 sets, 1 front, 1 rear.
(I too am having issues posting a pic, but this link)
https://militarymatters.online/defense-news/358-vs-scan-eagle-anti-drone-action/
I surmise using the center set of fins requires moving the rear ones to the very back position.
Why do they need all those? Unknown, but possibly different flight profiles need different surfaces.

Actually, the last image in the latter article shows a single set of rear mounts, and also a different shape of the rear fins. So, possibly the official photos were showing some prototype and they'd not yet decided on the rear fins shape or their exact position.

The photo in that article is from a specimen captured in 2020 on dhow see p.8 https://www.dia.mil/Portals/110/Documents/News/Military_Power_Publications/Seized_at_Sea.pdf OTOH from the same source, the photo in my Q is from a 2023 expo. So, another explanation is that they might have introduced the extra mount points for the rear fins, as well as alternate shape fins later on. The expo fins are far less angled [compared to the 2020 ones], so this might give the missile more flight time, due to extra lift.
